# postfix alias maildir delivering to ~user/Maildir/ instead of ~user/Maildir/alias/

Tags: postfix, alias

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
# rpm -q postfix
postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.i686
#
```

I switched `home_mailbox` from `Mailbox` to `Maildir/`:

```
# postconf -n | grep home_mailbox
home_mailbox = Maildir/
#
```

I'm sending myself a test email: `test+A@example.org`, yet email gets delivered to `test@example.org` instead, for whatever reason(s) it ignores my `+A` alias.

My goal is for `test+A@example.org` to get delivered to `~test/Maildir/.A/` and not into `~test/Maildir/`.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: You can do that with sieve and the FS-Layout of Maildir. Use dovecot as LDA and activate sieve, then write a sieve script that moves the mails according to the local part of the address.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Did my solution below work in your case? :)

Answer (score 2):

Here the extended version of [@sebix's comment above](https://serverfault.com/questions/701031/postfix-alias-maildir-delivering-to-user-maildir-instead-of-user-maildir-alia#comment867172_701031). This *untested* solution taken directly from dovecot 2 wiki: [Pigeonhole Sieve examples](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Plus_Addressed_mail_filtering).

---

You need [subaddress](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233) extension from dovecot sieve to do it. Put it in sieve script. Here the simple example to put email foo+spam@example.org to **Spam** folder.

```
require ["fileinto", "envelope", "subaddress"];
if envelope :detail "to" "spam"{
  fileinto "Spam";
}
```

The more advanced example is use regex to capture the address extension and put it in same folder. For example test+A@example.org will delivered on **A** subfolder, test+B@example.org will delivered on **B** subfolder and so on

```
require ["variables", "envelope", "fileinto", "subaddress"];
if envelope :is :user "to" "test" {
  if envelope :matches :detail "to" "*" {
    /* Save name in ${name} in all lowercase except for the first letter.
     * Joe, joe, jOe thus all become 'Joe'.
     * Of course you can set into all lowercase letter
     */
    set :lower :upperfirst "name" "${1}";
  }

  if string :is "${name}" "" {
    /* Default case to INBOX */
    fileinto "INBOX";
  } else {
    fileinto "${name}";
  }
}
```

---

To work with Postfix, this requires that the envelope "to" still contains the full address, so pass it with the -a flag.

For local delivery set

```
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -a "$RECIPIENT"
```

or for virtual delivery

```
dovecot unix    -       n       n       -       -      pipe
  flags=DRhu user=mail:mail argv=/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda
  -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -a ${recipient}
```